# Javascript Compare Date and Time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have two date time strings formated like so; 29/09/2009 15:19 & 29/09/2009 17:19 and basiclly all i want to do is compare the two date and time to see which is greater

Any Help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if ( Date.parse ( firstDateString ) > Date.parse ( secondDateString ) ) {
    // first date is greater
}
```

Comment: Note: Date.parse may not work with ambiguous US/UK dates. In the expample given, it should work, but other UK dates may not. You may need to convert the date to a US format first.